# Is it possible to make my ViewZone not blocked by margin

Tags: monaco-editor

I'm now using Monaco Editor to do a Code Review Editor with ViewZone to insert my review component, and now there is a problem I cannot find a better way to figure out.

The problem is: Let's say there is a `span` in my component which has a absolute position, and I want to make it shown above the `margin` area. The following is my [demo](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/playground.html#interacting-with-the-editor-listening-to-mouse-events).

[image]

So is it possible to implement this ?

Comment: What is the "margin" area? And what do you mean by "blocked"? In what sense is the view zone blocked? When you examine the DOM you will see that all the content is absolutely positioned to make rendering virtual (only render lines that are currently in view).

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please copy and paste the code inside the text of your question instead of putting a picture, you will get more answers.